# Touchpad alienware ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, touchpad, alienware

my touchpad stop working. I tried to enable it by fn+f3 or the hot keys from my Alienware user's guide fn+insert or fn+f11 but nothing work. Moreover I have already try to update my Synaptics but nothing even if I try xinput my touchpad doesn't appear in pointer devices neither mouse and touchpad. Something weird also it's when I try to click in the icon pointer devices (the one that appear next to mouse and touchpad when you write in control mouse) it gives me an error. Thanks in advance for any advice or comment.

Comment: Shall we guess what hardware do you have?

Comment: An Alienware 14